# Generate a random matrix in R with m columns and n rows where rows sum to 1

Tags: r

I want to generate an nxm matrix. Suppose its 100x3.  I want each row to sum to 1 (so two "0"'s and one "1").

```
sample(c(0,0,1),3)
```

will give me 1 row but is there a very fast way to generate the whole matrix without an rbind?

Thank you!

Comment: `t(replicate(100,sample(c(0,0,1))))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No loops, no transposition.  Just create a matrix of zeros and replace one entry per row with 1 by sampling the rows.

```
m <- matrix(0, 100, 3)
nr <- nrow(m)
m[cbind(1:nr, sample(ncol(m), nr, TRUE))] <- 1

all(rowSums(m) == 1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mat <- matrix(runif(300),ncol=3)
mat[] <- as.numeric(t(apply(mat, 1, function(r) r == max(r))))
```

Comment: I think the question wants discrete values of $0$ or $1$

Comment: Hi, not quite what I need. Each row needs to be two 0's and one 1. This isu uniform.

Answer (score 2):

```
 t(apply(t(matrix(rep(c(0,0,1),300),nrow = 3)), 1, function(x) sample(x)))
```

Comment: Not quite what I need. This puts all the ones in the 3rd column.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want single 1 for a row, the problem can be restated to select a column entry randomly that has 1 for each row.

So you can do like,

```
m <- 3; n<-100    
rand_v <- floor(runif(n)*3)+1
mat <- matrix(0,n,m)
idx <- cbind(1:n,rand_v)
mat[idx] <- 1
```

Hope this helps.