# Generating binary matrix with number of 1's fixed within a range

Tags: r, matrix, random

How to generate a binary matrix with random number of `1s` within a specific range, say between two to five, and at random positions?

I have tried `matrix(sample(0:1, 10, replace = T), 5, 10)`, but I have no control of the number of `1s` being generated.

Expected random output:

```
## each row has number of 1s in range(2,5)

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     0     ## four 1s at row 1
 [2,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0     1     ## three 1s at row 2
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0     0     ## two 1s at row 3
 [4,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     1     ## five 1s at row 4
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     0     ## four 1s at row 5
```

Comment: Have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945748/generate-a-random-matrix-in-r-with-m-columns-and-n-rows-where-rows-sum-to-1.  You could start with a matrix of zeros, sample 2:5 for the columns, then replace

Comment: `t(replicate(5, {i <- sample(2:5, 1); sample(c(rep(1, i), rep(0, 10 - i)))}))`

Comment: thank you, both answers solved my problem!